# Redirect function is working properly in localhost.but it's not working in live server

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function delete_app()
{
    $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->db->set('is_delete',1);
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->update('app');
    redirect("main_controller/display_app/-2");
}
```

Comment: are you sure you don't need header("Location:..."); here?

Comment: header function is working. but i just want to know why redirect function is not working there. @RussJ

Comment: I don't think there is such a keyword as "redirect" in PHP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php

Answer (score 0):

redirect resides in URL helper so assumed it as you have load it.
you can use location or refresh but sometime location has a issues in working.

try this:-
redirect('/account/login', 'refresh');